# How to read binary file data into arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, file, binaries

Attempt to read a binary file in python.  From the [dataset page](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html):

> The pixels are stored as unsigned chars (1 byte) and take values from
>   0 to 255

I have tried the following, which prints `(0,)`, rather than a 784,000 digit array.

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
# Processed MNIST dataset (http://cis.jhu.edu/~sachin/digit/digit.html)
import struct

f = open('data/data0', mode='rb')
data = []

print struct.unpack('<i', f.read(4))
```

How can I read this binary into either a 784,000 digit array (28 bytes x 28 bytes x 1k samples), or a 28x28x1000 3D array.  I have never worked with binaries before, and am quite confused!

Comment: Just food for thought, some existing work using Python read MNIST digits image. https://github.com/sorki/python-mnist/blob/master/mnist/loader.py

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`f.read()` will get you an immutable array of 784,000 bytes (called a `str` in Python 2). If you need it to be mutable, you can use the [`array` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html) and its array type capable of storing various primitives, unsigned bytes (represented by the `B` code) included:

```
from array import array

data = array('B')

with open('data/data0', 'rb') as f:
    data.fromfile(f, 784000)
```

This can be sliced as necessary:

```
EXAMPLE_SIZE = 24 * 24
examples = [data[s:s + EXAMPLE_SIZE] for s in xrange(0, len(a), EXAMPLE_SIZE)]
```